# Hive - How to get results from 'describe table' into temp table or cte

Tags: hive, common-table-expression, describe

I'm trying to run describe on a bunch of hive tables and would like to create a bunch of cte's and then UNION them.  Something like this:

```
With t1 as (describe sch1.tab1)
, t2 as (describe sch1.tab2)
, t3 as (describe sch1.tab3)
select *
from t1 UNION
select *
from t2 UNION
select * 
from t3
```

Unfortunately I'm getting this error when I try to do so:

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:15 Failed to recognize predicate 'describe'. Failed rule: 'identifier' in table name
```

Any suggestions for how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add all describe commands in a .hql and use `sort -u` command to perform a `UNION`.

```
hive -f desc_tables.hql  | sort -u
```